# Docker image works once then sometimes refuses to allow connections to localhost after file changes in Visual Studio, 127.0.0.1 works

Tags: windows, docker, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Okay, here's the setup: Visual Studio 2022, a working ASP.Net Core project (Blazor WASM) and Docker Desktop for Windows.

The whole setup works reliably if I build the project right after booting up: I see the server coming up, listening to the ports 80 and 443 which are then exposed as a random port & 7282. The browser then connects to https://localhost:7282 and **everything** works as intended. No errors anywhere.

But as it is with developing, sometimes you have to do code changes. So you stop the running project - without Docker this can be done through two methods: You either click "Stop" in VS2022 or simply close the browser window. Both lead to a shutdown of the running dev project.

Now, when I do *either* of those two, upon next startup the browser will not connect to https://localhost:7282 anymore. Simply nothing will happen and after an eternity I'll get a "connection timeout". Docker Desktop log shows a running project without errors.
I haven't yet found rhyme or reason as to which shutdown method creates the problem under which circumstances.

However: When I then try to connect to the running project through https://127.0.0.1:7282/ it works. Throws up a certificate error but it works.

Oh, and simply shutting down Docker / restarting Docker / deleting the container / deleting the image doesn't do anything. Only a full reboot will fix this.

This is very weird and I don't quite know what to do about that.

Comment: Okay, my laptop is showing the exact same problem. And that one is rather "virgin" when it comes to configuration so it shouldn't be something I messed up somewhere.

Comment: Okay, a clean/purge didn't work. But what did work was switching from WSL2 to HyperV.   On my laptop I also switched back to WSL2 afterwards and then that variant also worked.